# What is the meaning of "commit" and "abort" in a transaction?

Tags: database, transactions, operating-system, commit, abort

I am new to distributed technology. I always see these two words with transactions, but I cannot find definition on google.

Can anyone please help to explain them?

Comment: here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction

Comment: That is strange but my [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=commit%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cabort%E2%80%9D+in+a+transaction%3F) gives a few results...

Comment: Yes, it did give some results, but none of them are explaining these two terms generally, but only present how or where to use commit and abort..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Commit` simply means to permanently save all the changes which you have made in the current transaction. And, `Abort` means to disrupt the action by killing the current ongoing transaction. Generally, a term `Rollback` is used which refers to reverting to a previous stable state in the case of transactions.

Suppose, I am booking a ticket and in case the whole process is successfully done, then the server commits the transaction on a whole. Else,if there is any problem like power failure or any other problem, then your process is aborted and return backs to a previously created stable state.

I hope this helps. Feel free to comment if you couldn't understand further!

Comment: Thanks for answering. If the transaction was not committed yet, has the thread actually updated things in the remote server? Or only the "commit" make the updating?

Comment: No,actually there is a separate buffer area which stores all the events copy since last commit,I'm actually unable to remember it's name right now,SORRY! And,all the current transactions are done in a separate copy of that data,hence,any action if undone,is not saved and if committed is saved permanently in that buffer only! Feel free to ask doubts if still unclear.